# what's the precise name of command, 'shift + r'?

Tags: shortcut

Today, when I study blender with You tube video, I saw the hotkey 'shift+r', which seems to redo last action.

I want to know precise command name of it in case of forgetting that hot key.

If I know the precise name of it, i would find it with 'space bar'(what's the command name of this?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is 'Repeat Last'. You can view and edit the shortcuts in the 'Input' section of the Blender Preferences.